# Return Type incompatible: Mutators & Method Chaining

Tags: java, method-chaining

Let's consider this piece of code as our example:

```
import java.awt.*;

class Maze extends Panel{

    String name;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Maze m = new Maze();
        System.out.println(m.setName("Hello World").getName());
    }

    public Maze setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void paint(){

    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand method chaining, and as what answers said on other questions, use `return this`. I tried it and yes it works, but not on mutator methods like the method `setName()` above. Why is the compiler outputting:

```
The return type is incompatible with Component.setName(String)
```

Comment: It compiles just fine with me. Are you sure you are not extending Component?

Comment: Your code does the assignemnt the wrong way around: `name = this.name;` This is unrelated to your original question.

Comment: I have edited the question, it's suppose to be extending the `Panel` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless Maze derives from some other class that defined `setName(String)`, the `Maze setName(String name)` signature should be perfectly acceptable

Note: You should write `this.name = name;`

UPDATE: as it turns out, Maze *is* deriving from a `Panel` (which is deriving from `Component`).  As `Component.setName(String)` specifies its return type as `void` (`void setName(String)`), you cannot specify any other return type, but `void` for `setName()` in your class.  The reason is inheritance:  if someone has a reference to your `Maze` object via a `Component` reference (e.g. `Component c = new Maze();`), and calls `setName()`, the runtime knows to call yours, because of the inheritance.  However your version is returning a value, with which the runtime has to do something, but the code is not prepared for it (it was compiled with the knowledge of a `Component`.

Comment: I have edited the question, it's suppose to be extending the `Panel` class.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense :)

Comment: On your update, i didn't specify the return type as void on `setName()`

Comment: Well I guess it was just about overriding methods. Thanks all.

Answer (score 8):

The code you've given should be fine.

However, I suspect the problem is that your *real* code is a class extending `Component`, and you're trying to *override* `setName`.

Perhaps instead, you could write a `withName` method, like this:

```
public Maze withName(String name) {
    setName(name); // Inherited method
    return this;
}
```

... although you should be aware that `withXyz` is often used in APIs to create a *new* instance of a type (particularly immutable types) rather than modifying an existing instance.

Comment: ah Yes, it was extending the `panel` class.